# What are the powers of a Druid?

Tags: shannara, shannara-chronicles

In ***The Shannara Chronicles*** there are druids who possess magical powers. Allanon was the main druid in the TV series. What are the magical powers of a Druid?

Comment: https://shannara.fandom.com/wiki/Druid may be a good place to start.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots For some reason almost all the links lead to Wikipedia (and are useless redirects to "Shannara") instead of within the actual wiki.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Allanon's powers specifically (TV version)](https://shannara.fandom.com/wiki/Allanon)

- Mind reading
- Druid fire

**Changes made for the TV Adaptation**

> - Along with his magic, Allanon carries a sword and engages in physical combat quite frequently in the TV series; in the original trilogy he fights almost solely with his magic, the Druid fire.
> - Allanon regularly uses his Druid cave as a quick way to heal himself from serious injuries. In the books, Allanon has no such recourse, aside from the Druid Sleep which would put him to sleep for decades, if not longer.

[Druids in general](https://shannara.fandom.com/wiki/Druid)

> It's elemental magic: draws from the earth, air, fire and water in various forms.

- Can use a talisman
- Can use a form of astral projection
- Can blend into their surroundings (illusion magic)
- Can receive visions or premonitions
- Can locate individuals within the Four Lands
- Can heal/rejuvenate by using Druid Sleep (a type of suspended animation)
- Can extend own life by using Druid Sleep
- Can communicate with people and animals (Walker Boh / Whisper) using a form of telepathy
- Can create artifacts of powerful magic (Druids of the past)

Comment: Notably however, most druids in the books also rely on their own magic specialization and other skills not related to the druid powers specifically. Elven magic, alchemy etc. Walker Boh for example was a skilled mage long before he became a druid - partially because of his Ohmsford heritage, partially because of Cogline's teachings. The ability to communicate with animals might originate from his ancestor Kimber Boh. And so on.

Comment: Btw one important ability missing from the list: the ability to summon the spirit of dead druids. This is something recurring throughout the books.